# C/ObjC - parameter size. Using a pointer vs value

Tags: c++, c, parameter-passing

at what point should I be passing a pointer to data in my functions/methods, rather than just passing the value?

Obviously there's the cases where I want the function to operate on the given data, but what if I'm just passing the value for info/copying purposes?

For example, foo as a basic type:

```
void setFoo(int foo);
...
int foo = 1;
setFoo(foo);
```

Now foo as a simple structure:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Foo;

void setFoo(Foo foo);
...
Foo foo = {1, 2};
setFoo(foo);   // Apple code does this kind of thing with CGSize, CGPoint...
```

But what if foo is a bigger struct...

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    char str[256];
} Foo;

void setFoo(Foo *foo);  // Now taking a pointer instead.
...
Foo foo = {1, 2, 3, etc ... };
setFoo(&foo);
```

**Q.** At what point here should I start using a pointer when providing data to a function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When on embedded systems, I think it's good practice to pass pointers (or references) for anything that's not a primitive type.  This way your struct can grow and add members as needed without affecting the amount of data that is copied.  Needless copying is a good way to slow down your system, so avoid it when you can.  Getting into that habit will help in the long run I think.

Comment: Yes, I've always used pointers (or references) for anything larger than a basic type (e.g. int, float).  However, the reason I'm asking is that I've noticed Apple is regularly passing and returning CGSize, CGPoint structure types, without using pointers. So I'm wondering what the threshold here is.  I had presumed, a long time ago, that the threshold was the word size on the platform, but that does not appear to be true, at least for Apple's code.

Comment: I'm guessing as you approach the width of the bus, you'll want to consider passing pointers.

Comment: So there's no hard and fast rule? Mostly just a performance/habit rule?  I noticed that Apple's CoreGraphics thinks nothing about passing around CGRect types, which are comprised of 4 floats.  I'm thinking that if they can do that sort of thing as an integral part of high performance graphics on everything from the iPod to the Mac, I could save myself some trouble in the parameter-passing department, too.

Comment: I would say there is no hard/fast rule.  Like the other answer says, it's a matter of how you intend to use the function.  For instance, I bet a lot of the CoreGraphics stuff wouldn't want to pass pointers in case of accidental modification.  And the data is small enough where it can be copied quickly

Answer (score 0):

If you use references and/or pointers to [const] objects as appropriate, "when" becomes "all the time"

Comment: Could you please define "appropriate"?  For example: passing an integer is an obvious case of where it would be inappropriate to use a pointer.  But what of something like CGSize or CGPoint?

Comment: When passing anything larger than a pointer that isn't a native type (e.g. double ) would be a good rule of thumb.

Comment: You also have to consider usage within the function and your compiler/execution platform.  If you are going to access it a billion times read-only, it might be faster overall to pass a large structure once and reference it directly off the stack frame than save a few microseconds passing a pointer to it and then wearing the cost of dereferencing a pointer a billion times or using non-stack memory.  No hard & fast rules but in the general case I would pass anything struct-like as a pointer with appropriate constness.  Season according to performance issues if they occur.